# Magento 1.9.1.0 broken static urls after installing SUPEE-9767 patch

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am experiencing strange problem when I apply SUPEE-9767 patch on Magento 1.9.1.0

I have seen there are several pages mentioning the same patch, but I haven't seen the same problem mentioned.

My problem is that all static urls (images, css files, js files) have this as a url:
`http://project.local/://project.local/skin/frontend/base/default/theme1/css/theme1.css`

Is there a known issue with url parsing in this patch? When I navigate to the branch that doesn't have patch applied everything works normal. I couldn't find which part of the code that was changed in the patch is actually making this problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was in 3rd party extension which overwrite `\Mage_Core_Model_Store::getBaseUrl`.